# 2-Dimensional array with different data type columns

Tags: vba

Code: VBA

Suppose there's an `8 X 2 array, val(1 to 8, 1 to 2)`.

I want the first column to be of **"String"** type and the second column to be of **"Long"** type.

Is it possible to define such a 2-D array?

Comment: I would recommend using a dedicated Class, much easier later on when trying to sort and manipulate the data

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim A(8,2) As Variant
```

Arrays are all the same type.

Recordsets are tables. This reads a text file and puts a random number as a double and a string into each record.

```
Randomize 
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        .AddNew
        .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
        .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
        .UpDate
    Loop
    .Sort = "RandomNumber"
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```