# Remove item from a list after I pick it

Tags: excel, vba

I want my code to pick a random number between 0 and 99, and then do it again 99 more times without picking a duplicate. I know how I'd do this in a very inefficient way (pick a random number and then check it against all numbers already picked, repicking if it is a duplicate).

I am sure that there is a better way, I just am not sure what to call the correct structure and thus I'm having a hard time getting the google results I need to figure this out.

What I think I need to do:

1. Build a "list" of 100 items, numbers 0 - 99.
2. Pick 1 item at random from that list, which will remove it from the list.
3. Pick from the entire list again, this time the list is 99 items in size.
4. Repeat until the list is empty

What is this called and what are the key concepts I need to understand?

Comment: Look at the collection or dictionary object and pick a random `index` as your selection, then remove, add the index to another collection to check it's existence i'd go for.  Or not even use a list to pick from just a random number and add to collection.

Comment: Use a dictionary and add the chosen number to the dictionary each time a new one is chosen. Dictionaries have an `.Exists` method you can use to see if it has already been added, so put it into a loop until it finds a number that does not already exist in the dictionary, also keeping track of when there are no more unique values possible.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Collections is exactly what I had in mind.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @braX I learned about VBA Dictionary tonight too.  Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

See [2-Dimensional array with different data type columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052114/2-dimensional-array-with-different-data-type-columns) Generate 0 to 99 then randomise the table.

Arrays are all the same type.

Recordsets are tables. This reads a text file and puts a random number as a double and a string into each record.

```
Randomize 
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        .AddNew
        .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
        .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
        .UpDate
    Loop
    .Sort = "RandomNumber"
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Keep in mind that using `Rnd()` without also calling `Randomize` before it will result in the number not actually being random, and can actually result in getting the same number every time.

Comment: I'm don't quite follow how to randomize the table.  However, I like the idea of doing this with an 2 dimensional array.  I'll come back to this when I'm rested.  Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question based on information I learned from the comments.

Here is how I did it using Collections:

```
Sub collections()
Randomize

Dim x As Byte
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim pick As Integer
Dim i As Byte: i = 1

For x = 0 To 99
    coll.Add x
Next

Do While coll.Count <> 0
    pick = Int((coll.Count - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    'Cells(i, 1).Value = coll.Item(pick)
    coll.Remove (pick)
    i = i + 1
Loop
end sub
```

A little long winded, but I wanted to check to be sure it was working right (hence write to the activesheet and i as a counter).

Here is how I did it using a Dictionary:

```
Sub dictionary()
Randomize

Dim dict As New Scripting.dictionary
Dim x As Byte
Dim pick As Integer
Dim i As Byte: i = 1

For x = 0 To 99
    Do
        pick = Int((99 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
    Loop Until Not dict.Exists(pick)
    dict.Add pick, 0
    'Cells(i, 4).Value = pick
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

And when I compared the two ways of doing it, the collections sub was always faster by ~ a factor of 10.

```
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim ElapsedTime As Double
Dim TotalTime As Double
Dim x As Byte

For x = 1 To 100
    StartTime = Timer
    Call collections
    ElapsedTime = Timer - StartTime
    TotalTime = TotalTime + ElapsedTime
Next
Debug.Print TotalTime & " Collections"

TotalTime = 0

For x = 1 To 100
    StartTime = Timer
    Call dictionary
    ElapsedTime = Timer - StartTime
    TotalTime = TotalTime + ElapsedTime
Next
Debug.Print TotalTime & " Dictionary"
```